# Doesn't autowiring limit goal of IoC?

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, autowired

IoC is nice but, used with autowiring (@EJB, @Autowired, @Inject, @SpringBean...), don't you think it limit a goal of IoC?

Actually i don't know so much about autowiring systems in different frameworks but it seems that it's mainly based on types.

When you use @EJB on IService then you need to have only one implementation ServiceImpl to make it work.

What if we want many implementations?

It seems some autowiring annotations can have arguments.
For exemple in Stripes you can do:
@SpringBean("xxxService")
Where xxxService is a spring initialized bean.

In such a case, ok you don't do "new XxxServiceImpl()"
But you still put a hardcoded reference to the service implementation you want to use in your bean. It's simply not a class reference but a spring bean reference to the implementation...

What do you think about that?
I like autowiring but just wonder myself....

Comment: I can't begin to guess what you think "entrave" means.

Comment: It seems like a french word: http://translate.google.com/#fr|en|entraver

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, there are limitations to autowiring (just one implementation of an autowired interface), so it defeats a part of the IoC flexibility when it comes to injecting the proper implementation.

However, I see autowiring as just being a way to reduce configuration. So when 90% of your dependencies can be autowired, you tend to end up with less configuration overall (and the remaining configuration is significant, because it only contains the important (implementation-specific) bits)

Comment: I think almost the same. Let's use autowiring on types and when 2 implementations remove autowiring :D

Answer (score 2):

I doubt this can be considered an objective question, but let's have a shot at this.

I've had quite some discussions about this, and it's certainly not only you that's thinking this way.

Yes, doing it that way makes IoC somewhat pointless.  It still makes it easier because you dont have to figure out the ideal wiring order yourself, but you lose the advantage of being able to switch implementations by changing a configuration file, which is one of the reasons we started with IoC in the first place.

There seem to be two main approaches to switching between implementations now:

1. Use Qualifiers

You can add an annotation on your implementation, and another one on your injection point, which will tell the container which one you want to use.  You still have to change your code in two spots though, so it's the same as implementing a sub-interface and wiring that by type.  It's also still hard-coded.

1. Use a beanconfigurer

Spring has this beanconfigurer concept, which just replaces the old xml files.  You can handle the configuration in a certain class which will tell the container how to wire.  I don't see the advantage over the old style (for this cause, xml syntax is more readable), but I guess it's a matter of taste.

For me, the only way to use autowiring by type in a decent way is to play with the classpath, so that you can pop in mocks instead of implementations by including a different class.  But since java classpath has such a user-friendly interface, I also don't think this is easier than the old xml way of doing things.

So in the end, I think it all comes down to a matter of taste.  Yes, autowiring using annotations is a lot easier, but it does hardcode your configuration into your code, just as you say.  The question becomes, does it really change that often that it warrants a 'softcoding' approach?

Comment: Using qualifiers ok but if you autowire a bean in 100 other beans, when you make another implementation you'll have to change the qualifier for the 100 other beans... And you'll base yourself on packages and a string (bean reference) to do that so it can be error prone... i don't like so much this way ^^

Comment: @OrangeDog yep it's what i thought, but it's not an elegant solution ^^ It would mean having for exemple 2 bean names "usedService" "notUsedService" and switch the names when needed. It works but i don't like so much this solution.

Comment: @Sebastien Lorber - In that situation, why does the bean for "notUsedService" exist at all? It should be at minimum commented out. See my answer for an example of using qualifiers in a more maintainable and semantic way.

Answer (score 2):

In response to comments, an example of semantic bean names instead of "usedService" and "notUsedService". A common system will have some data sharded between servers, but some stored in only one place.

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("customerDataSource")
DataSource ds;

@Autowired
@Qualifier("geoipDataSource")
DataSource geoip;
```

and in the xml:

```
<bean id="customerDataSource" class="...ShardedDataSource">
  <property name="dataSources">
    <list>
      <value><ref local="ds1"/>
      <value><ref local="ds2"/>
    </list>
  </property>
</bean>

<bean id="ds1" class="...DataSource">
  ...
</bean>

<bean id="ds2" class="...DataSource">
  ...
</bean>

<alias name="ds2" alias="geoipDataSource"/>
```

Comment: And of course, you don't need to change any code if you don't want to use sharding, just give the bean name to a regular data source.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [autowiring by name](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/beans.html). Which will solve your problem.

If you have a hard requirement for autowiring by type. Then you can specify like this,

```
<bean id="PersonBean1" class="com.mkyong.common.Person">
        <property name="name" value="mkyong1" />
        <property name="address" value="address 1" />
        <property name="age" value="28" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="PersonBean2" class="com.mkyong.common.Person">
        <property name="name" value="mkyong2" />
        <property name="address" value="address 2" />
        <property name="age" value="28" />
    </bean>
```

and you can specify the bean in your class like,

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;

public class Customer 
{
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("PersonBean1")
    private Person person;
    private int type;
    private String action;
    //getter and setter methods
}
```

Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: Actually it's what i said about name.I mean you put an implementation name in your code. It's perhaps not a class name but it's still an implementation reference that is hardcoded in your code (like my @SpringBean exemple)

Comment: @Sebastien Lorber - But the bean names are not hardcoded. You can freely change the configuration to give the correct bean the correct name.

Comment: @Sebastien Lorber What you mean by hardcoding? We are setting up the container. If you want to set it up differently then of course you have to change something. In this case it happens to be in the code. That's why some people dont prefer Autowired annotation.

Comment: exactly but you change it in the exact same file where you would have done a "new xxx()" -> changing in the code mean changing all qualifiers referencing this bean. OrangeDog method (changing bean name in xml) is better for me.